# jQuery $(document).ready didn't work in phpfox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, phpfox

I'm developing a PHPFox Module where I use a jQuery Plugin to paginate a serie of images. When I access the module the plugin doesn't work, but the rest of the js code have no problem. The only code that doesn't work is which is placed inside the `$(document).ready` event. If I refresh the page the plugin starts to work.

I think the problem is caused for the cache of the CMS, because the DOM isn't reloaded when I load the Module. I tried to change de `$(document).ready` for `window.onload` but I've the same problem.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Is the jQuery library included?

Comment: Don't worry, I've fixed it changing $(document).ready for $Behaviour.onLoadEvents = function(){rest of the code}

Comment: You can answer your own question with what you have found and accept it later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've find the solution:

To use jQuery functions on load in phpfox you must use the sintax *$Behaviour.onLoadEvents = function(){rest of the code}* insted of the traditional and standar *$(document).ready*

Comment: Note that the variable is $Behavior rather than what you wrote ($Behaviour).  It's the American spelling :)